# Why does EEEA get to do what ever he wants and close questions because he wants proof of troubleshooting?

Tags: discussion, moderators

The title says it all. Why does this site allow EEEA to close comments until he receives proof like he is a judge.

Comment: A watery tart threw a sword at him.

Comment: Help, help, I'm being repressed!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's ranty whining.

Comment: BEHOLD THE VIOLENCE! (and closevotes) INHERENT IN THE SYSTEM!

Answer (score 12):

I am not a judge, but the ServerFault community *did* elect me to help ensure that questions and answers exchanged here meet certain standards. In the case of [your question](https://serverfault.com/questions/851433/ip-tables-locks-me-out-on-logout), not enough details were provided. The on-hold reason I chose speaks to this:

> "Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must
>   include the desired end state, the specific problem or error,
>   sufficient information about the configuration and environment to
>   reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear
>   problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to
>   get good answers."

Being on hold is not a death sentence for a question. Rather, it's a way to communicate that significant improvements need to be made. I gave you examples of what those improvements were, hoping to guide you in the right direction.

Instead of taking my advice, you chose to insult and threaten me, the person who was trying to help you. Not a great strategy for someone looking for help.

So, hopefully you'll be able to take a deep breath and come back with the information requested. If and when that happens, we will be glad to help you out.

Comment: The lack of troubleshooting close reason is appropriate, but it could also have been closed as "unclear what you're asking," or maybe even because it's something to do with virtualmin...  One way or another, closing was the right action.

Answer (score 10):

Firstly, your question wasn't a question. It was a statement of a problem that you're having. What should our response be? `"Cool story, bro. Good luck."` What were you expecting as a response to your statement?

Secondly, you showed no research or troubleshooting effort. Now maybe it's the case that you've done some preliminary research and troubleshooting but we'd have no way of knowing that from what you stated. We're left to assume that you haven't done anything to this point. Perhaps you think the site is a place where you can dump your issue on the page and have the community figure it out for you, sans any effort on your part.

The close seems perfectly valid in light of what you've given us to work with.